# MS Chart Control : Annotations do not display when using FastLines

Tags: c#, charts

When using Fastlines, ***annotations do not show up*** in the Chart 
(Whatever the nature of the annotation)
This is very annoying and I've read through the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.aspx) on the subject, there is no trace of such a restriction.
If anybody can confirm that freak/buggy behavior and offer some workaround, he's very welcome.

The only ugly trick i've found is to plot a duplicate transparent line and anchor the annotations to its points.. At least, I hope this post will avoid other developers screwing their nights on this.

The more I use MS Chart Control (Ex-Dundas) the more I'm getting used to dirty hacks like these.
Just one among [too many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221404/ms-chart-control-two-x-axis-one-for-hours-another-for-days-or-mixing-both) night/sleep/life spoiler for developers.

**EDIT :** 
To asnwer a code sample request :

```
  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
  series1.ChartArea = myChartArea.Name;
  series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
  series1.Legend = "Default";
  series1.Name = "Series1";
  this.chart.Series.Add(series1);

  Random random = new Random();
  for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
   series1.Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddHours(pointIndex), random.Next(5, 60));

  RectangleAnnotation annotation = new RectangleAnnotation();
  annotation.AnchorDataPoint = series1.Points[1];
  annotation.Text = "Just Won't Work";
  annotation.ForeColor = Color.Black;
  annotation.Font = new Font("Arial", 12); ;
  annotation.LineWidth = 2;

  chart.Annotations.Add(annotation);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I tested it and you're right...

Also, quoting from this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489249.aspx):

> The FastLine chart type is a variation
>   of the Line chart that significantly
>   reduces the drawing time of a series
>   that contains a very large number of
>   data points. Use this chart in
>   situations where very large data sets
>   are used and rendering speed is
>   critical.
>
> **Some charting features are omitted** from the FastLine chart to improve
>   performance. The features omitted
>   include control of point level visual
>   attributes, markers, data point
>   labels, and shadows.

If you really need `Annotations`, I think you should switch to `Line` Chart...

Comment: "Some charting features are omitted" Well, Bravo to MS for the exhaustive precision. That's too bad and disappointing, cause I got both needs : I do have Millions of points to plot, AND i want to Plot some signals when they occur. Anyway, i'll make do with it (and switch back to Zedgraph when I have time :-) )

Answer (score 2):

One Workaround Solution I've implemented to meet my specific needs is to put annotations into an extra Line Series having BorderWidth set to 0 so the line does not display, containing only the points that I want to be annotated.

So I have 2 series, one with SeriesChartType "FastLine", and another one (invisible) with SeriesChartType "Line" with some points from the first series where I want my annotations (visible).

Hacky but it works and do not blow performance if you do not haev thousands of annotations.

Comment: You can also try to hide the `Series` using `Series.Enabled`, and to be even faster, create a point series instead of a line one (I guess it will need less computation to draw points instead of lines)

Comment: Thank You diGGy diGGy, Good Point. I feel less lonely in the rickety World of MS Chart Control :-)